# Remove multiple XML namespaces from the XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have to remove multiple xml namespaces from the XML file. Due to some requirement we are doing appending for the each incoming message. so in the final file we need to remove the below XML namespaces.
All namespaces are same only. need to remove those duplicate namespaces.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Test xmlns:ns0="urn:demo:in:file">
<Header><Name>ABC</Name>
 <no>1234</no> 
<FileName>Invoice</FileName>
</Header>
<Detail>
  <Id>
 <Type>1</Type>
 <Customerno>2</Customerno>
 <Group>3</Group>
  </Id>
 </Detail>
 </ns0:Test>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ns0:Test xmlns:ns0="urn:demo:in:file">
  <Header>
  <Name>DEF</Name>
  <no>1235</no>
 <FileName>Invoice2</FileName>
</Header>
<Detail><Id>
<Type>2</Type>
<Customerno>3</Customerno>
 <Group>4</Group>
  </Id>
  </Detail>
 </ns0:Test>
```

In the above file we have 2 xml namespaces but in the output it should be one xml namespace and nodes should be under that namespaces. Below is the expected output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ns0:Test xmlns:ns0="urn:demo:in:file">
<Header>
 <Name>ABC</Name>
 <no>1234</no>
 <FileName>Invoice</FileName>
</Header>
 <Detail>
  <Id>
 <Type>1</Type>
 <Customerno>2</Customerno>
    <Group>3</Group>
      </Id>
  </Detail>
  <Header>
 <Name>DEF</Name>
   <no>1235</no>
  <FileName>Invoice2</FileName>
  </Header>
    <Detail>
     <Id>
     <Type>2</Type>
     <Customerno>3</Customerno>
      <Group>4</Group>
      </Id>
    </Detail>
 </ns0:Test>
```

Please help me with this to achieve the expected output.

Regards,
Janardhan

Comment: Your input is not well-formed XML and cannot be processed by XSLT.

Comment: Maybe you are searching for this: exclude-result-prefixes="#all"

Comment: I want to remove the prefixes of xml namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not (just) about namespaces. It seems you are trying to concatenate XML documents. However...

1. the  processing instruction is only allowed at the beginning of a document, not in the middle. So appending something that starts with that line is bad already.
2. XML needs one top level element per document. If you append something after that top level element it is bad again.

So what you need to do is to introduce a new top level element, then add all your documents' top level element as subelement to the new top level. Only then you can think of namespaces and try to make the output more efficient.